Pybit websocket streaming assign to specific IP address (static)?
https://pypi.org/project/pybit/
I have a PC with multiple ethernet ports, is it possible for Pybit websocket streaming python program to assign to specific port?
Scenario example:

Python program A is running ws streaming, I want it to use Ethernet 1
Python program B is running ws streaming, I want it to use Ethernet 2
Python program C is running ws streaming, I want it to use Ethernet 3

The reason I want to do so, because all the internet service providers in my country are kind of sucks, they tend to disconnect sometimes, at least I have multiple WS to backup, that's the intention.
Hopefully anyone can help and tell me how I can edit the Pybit library... Thanks
Update: After investigate deeper, the library that I need to edit is not pybit, it's socket
